# SWIFT - Problems with navigationController using .xib files - when a i present a new viewController, navigation Controller does not follow up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

when using storyboard, i just need to "embed Navigation Controller" to have all my viewControllers with navigationController

i've started to use .xib files instead of storyboard

well i've set ONE viewController on sceneDelegate as root already

is a tableView, and when one of the cells are clicked i present a new viewController

but the navigationViewController does not follow up this new viewController

i want to have a navigationController on this new viewController too

I DONT WANT TO USE A TABBAR

here the code that i set my root viewController

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        /// 1. Capture the scene
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        /// 2. Create a new UIWindow using the windowScene constructor which takes in a window scene.
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        /// 3. Create a view hierarchy programmatically
        let categoryVC = CategoryViewController()
        let todoVC = TodoViewController()
        
        let categoryNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: categoryVC)
        let todoNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: todoVC)
        
        
        
        /// 4. Set the root view controller of the window with your view controller
        window.rootViewController = categoryNC
        
        /// 5. Set the window and call makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

here is how im presenting a new viewController clicking on cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //deselect cell
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            todoViewController.selectCategory = categoryBrain.categoryArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        todoViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(todoViewController, animated: true)
```

sorry for my english, im working to improve.
thank you in advance s2.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between present and push? `navigationController?.pushViewController(todoViewController...`

Comment: Where do you declare `todoViewController`?

Comment: Also you can just use `indexPath` instead of `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` as it would reference the IndexPath of the `didSelectRowAt` method.